# Checking the same value in different row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I just start to learn MySQL, and I have a question regarding one specific query. I have a table called 'table1' as following :

[image]

I want to know if there are different rows with the same value of Gender, age, and postcode. In this case, the query should display :

[image]

For now, in order to solve this problem, I just use GROUP BY and check them manually:

```
 SELECT * FROM table1
 GROUP BY Gender, age, postcode
```

But for bigger data, it will be too hard to do check them manually.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: I would expect to see aggregate functions (count,sum for example) with a group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Query like this:

```
    SELECT t1.Gender, t1.Age, t1.Postcode FROM table1 t1
    GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(Gender, Age, postcode)
    HAVING sum(1) >1
) f
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
     ON t2.Gender = f.Gender AND t2.Age = f.Age AND t2.postcode = f.postcode

ORDER BY t2.postcode, t2.Age, t2.Gender;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> select * from table1;
+------+--------+------+----------+-----------+
| Name | Gender | age  | postcode | member_id |
+------+--------+------+----------+-----------+
| A    | M      |   18 | 2112     |     10001 |
| B    | M      |   19 | 2012     |     10002 |
| C    | F      |   23 | 1345     |     10003 |
| D    | M      |   23 | 3145     |     10004 |
| F    | M      |   23 | 4567     |     10005 |
| G    | F      |   21 | 1022     |     10006 |
| H    | M      |   18 | 2112     |     10007 |
| I    | F      |   21 | 8694     |     10008 |
| J    | F      |   25 | 7865     |     10009 |
| K    | F      |   24 | 7869     |     10010 |
| L    | F      |   21 | 1022     |     10011 |
+------+--------+------+----------+-----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT t2.* FROM (
    ->     SELECT t1.Gender, t1.Age, t1.Postcode FROM table1 t1
    ->     GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(Gender, Age, postcode)
    ->     HAVING sum(1) >1
    -> ) f
    -> LEFT JOIN table1 t2
    ->      ON t2.Gender = f.Gender AND t2.Age = f.Age AND t2.postcode = f.postcode
    ->
    -> ORDER BY t2.postcode, t2.Age, t2.Gender;
+------+--------+------+----------+-----------+
| Name | Gender | age  | postcode | member_id |
+------+--------+------+----------+-----------+
| L    | F      |   21 | 1022     |     10011 |
| G    | F      |   21 | 1022     |     10006 |
| H    | M      |   18 | 2112     |     10007 |
| A    | M      |   18 | 2112     |     10001 |
+------+--------+------+----------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a self join

`select * from t t1, t t2 where (t1.x = t2.x)  and (t1.id != t2. id)`

note that x is the column you need to find duplicate in its values and id is the primary key

Answer (score -1):

To fetch the rows of data with duplicates do:

```
SELECT Gender, age, postcode, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Name), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT member_id)
FROM table1
GROUP BY Gender, age, postcode
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```